# Magento 2 Add sort order for images in frontend

Tags: magento2

I have a form in backend in which we save the details and the banner image is reflected on frontend. I can make multiple banners. Now i want to give them some sort order . For eg if i give the 2nd banner sort order of 1 it should appear first. I have attached the screenshots of frontend, backend form and backend entries

[image: Backend entries]

[image: Backend Form][image: Homepage]

Comment: where you want to apply that sort order on frontend or backend

Comment: i want to apply in  frontend for images

Comment: You have to add `order` attribute in your form then, you sort them

Answer (score 0):

First you create a field in your `table` and in your `backend form` to get and save the sort value against each image.

then on frontend order by your collection by sort order

```
$collection->setOrder('sort_order','ASC');
```

or

```
$collection->getSelect()->orderBy('sort_order');
```

`'sort_order`' is your column/field name in table

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: It didnot worked. I added field in backend form and then sorted them using usort function of php

Answer (score 0):

Create a sort_order field in your custom table and set the order, If you want to set the order based on the id then try this.

`$collection->setOrder('id','ASC');`